# cannot use import meta even though type module is enabled on github pages

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting this error on my website:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module`

here's the html that produces this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="#" rel="icon">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
<title>Blue Retro JS2023</title>
<style>* { background: #444444; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
body, #app { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
#app canvas {
image-rendering: pixelated;
width: min(99vw, calc(99vh * 16/9));
aspect-ratio: 16/9;
cursor: pointer;}</style>
  <script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body><div id="app"></div></body>
</html>
```

Here's the offending line in js file:

`n=""+new URL("out_0-e9a3fdb7.png",import.meta.url).href;`

Can you please help?

This error occurs when served from github pages, if I serve on my local machine I don't see this error.

### Edit

I found the build step of this line causes the issue, Issue is resolved when I removed this step:

`roadroller dist/assets/index.min.js -o dist/assets/index.min.js`

roadroller transforms the code to a single `eval()` function that expands into the above `import.meta` statement, something about that but I am not sure.

Comment: https://github.com/eguneys/blue-retro2023